# Ruby #union on Array reacts very strangely

Tags: arrays, ruby, union

I like to use the Array#union or #| method to return an array of objects where duplicates are removed. I have a custom implementation of `eql?` on my class.
There is a really strange behaviour if I do that. Up to 8 elements the union is just working fine but with more elements the duplicates are not removed. Is that actually a bug of ruby or do I miss something?

```
class A
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    self.name = name
  end

  def eql?(other)
    other.name.eql?(name)
  end
end

as = names.map { |name| A.new(name) }
bs = names.map { |name| A.new(name) }

as | bs
=>
[#<A:0x00007fe503692388 @name="a">,
 #<A:0x00007fe503692310 @name="b">,
 #<A:0x00007fe5036922e8 @name="c">,
 #<A:0x00007fe5036922c0 @name="d">,
 #<A:0x00007fe503692298 @name="e">,
 #<A:0x00007fe503692270 @name="f">,
 #<A:0x00007fe503692248 @name="g">,
 #<A:0x00007fe503692220 @name="h">,
 #<A:0x00007fe5036921f8 @name="i">,
 #<A:0x00007fe5036921d0 @name="j">,
 #<A:0x00007fe5036921a8 @name="k">,
 #<A:0x00007fe503692180 @name="l">,
 #<A:0x00007fe5035732e0 @name="a">,
 #<A:0x00007fe5035732b8 @name="b">,
 #<A:0x00007fe503573290 @name="c">,
 #<A:0x00007fe503573268 @name="d">,
 #<A:0x00007fe503573240 @name="e">,
 #<A:0x00007fe503573218 @name="f">,
 #<A:0x00007fe5035731f0 @name="g">,
 #<A:0x00007fe5035731c8 @name="h">,
 #<A:0x00007fe5035731a0 @name="i">,
 #<A:0x00007fe503573178 @name="j">,
 #<A:0x00007fe503573150 @name="k">,
 #<A:0x00007fe503573128 @name="l">]

as[0..7] | bs[0..7]
=>
[#<A:0x00007fe503692388 @name="a">,
 #<A:0x00007fe503692310 @name="b">,
 #<A:0x00007fe5036922e8 @name="c">,
 #<A:0x00007fe5036922c0 @name="d">,
 #<A:0x00007fe503692298 @name="e">,
 #<A:0x00007fe503692270 @name="f">,
 #<A:0x00007fe503692248 @name="g">,
 #<A:0x00007fe503692220 @name="h">]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to implement both `eql?` and `hash` methods with accordance to @engineersmnky's comment regarding [Object#eql?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F), that `eql?` expects the instance hashes to be the same

```
class A
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def eql?(other)
    other.name.eql?(@name)
  end

  def hash
    [@name].hash
  end
end

#declare inclusive range from 'a' to 'm'

names = 'a'..'m'

as = names.map { |name| A.new(name) }
bs = names.map { |name| A.new(name) }

as | bs
```

Outputs:

```
[#<A:0x0000558a74860020 @name="a">,
 #<A:0x0000558a7485bf98 @name="b">,
 #<A:0x0000558a7485bf70 @name="c">,
 #<A:0x0000558a7485bf48 @name="d">,
 #<A:0x0000558a7485bf20 @name="e">,
 #<A:0x0000558a7485bef8 @name="f">,
 #<A:0x0000558a7485bed0 @name="g">,
 #<A:0x0000558a7485bea8 @name="h">,
 #<A:0x0000558a7485bd90 @name="i">,
 #<A:0x0000558a7485bd40 @name="j">,
 #<A:0x0000558a7485bd18 @name="k">,
 #<A:0x0000558a7485bcf0 @name="l">,
 #<A:0x0000558a7485bcc8 @name="m">]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped. So, would you agree that the documentation is a bit misleading here? https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-7C

Comment: Yes, I think it is missing - from the older version the documentation used to present

Comment: @LarsSchirrmeister I am not sure misleading is correct. If you look at the docs for [`Object#eql?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F) it does state: *"For any pair of objects where `eql?` returns `true`, the `hash` value of both objects must be equal. So any subclass that overrides `eql?` should also override `hash` appropriately."* I think this is the appropriate place to document this and thus `Array#|` (union) just stating "items are compared using `eql?`" seems sufficient

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @engineersmnky

Comment: Oh, alright. I did not know that. Yes, you are right, then everything is fine. thank you @engineersmnky

Comment: `A = Struct.new(:name)` gives you the same behavior as the Class (it ships with `initialize`, `eql?` and `hash`).

Comment: Ha, also a good remark. Didn’t know that. Thank you.